# HTML + Alternative of Javascript Switch-Case for simple string & Constant

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement

In my Js script, I am using switch case but I dnt want to use it but I am not getting better alternative of this.

Here I am using Js CONSTANT as well for defining First URL & Second URL

```
var FIRST_URL  = "/first_url.html"
var SECOND_URL = "/second_url.html"
```

& also passing FIRST_URL and SECOND_URL as parameter from function. That's  why I used FIRST_URL with double quotes and without quotes.

**Snippet :-**

```
if(url == "DIV_ID"){

  switch (url_type) {
    case FIRST_URL:
    case "FIRST_URL":
      result = "/first_url.html";
      break;
    case SECOND_URL:
    case "SECOND_URL":
      result = "/second_url.html";
      break;
    default:
      result = "other_url.html";
      break;
  }
}
```

Suggest something to resolve this.

Comment: What's wrong with using a switch statement? If you don't like switch statements, why not just an if/else statement if there are only two options?

Comment: Actually Switch is better than normal if else.. better stick with this.. Or if you are having any other problem kindly explain it in the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this, but add proper error checking.

Roughtly:

```
var arr = {};
arr['FIRST'] = 'your first url';
arr['SECOND'] = 'your second url';
result = arr[urlType];
```

Comment: That's not an array. It's an object.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder used to call those structures associative arrays back in the days, pretty new to javascript thou, what's the actual name?

Comment: "Object." People also use the terms "map" and "dictionary," but now that ES2015 has real `Map`s (which would be appropriate here as well), expect "map" to start actually meaning `Map`. In JS-land, we don't call non-arrays arrays, just to avoid confusion. This even though [standard JS arrays aren't actually arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html). :-)

Comment: even if I don't fully agree, not being this my field of expertise I've changed the answer.

Comment: You can extend it a little bit `result = arr[urlType] || 'default value';` to provide ability to have default value

Answer (score 0):

here's an example using object literal:

```js
var arr = {
  FIRST : 'your first url',
  SECOND: 'your second url'
   };

console.log(arr.FIRST)
console.log(arr['SECOND'])

//for adding properties
 arr.thr='third prop';
```

basically the resulting obj is the same to bigmike's answer, but it maybe easier to understand .

This is what is called a key-value pair and the structure is an object (JS definitions).

BTW there is nothing wrong with switch .